# How can I get defined instance/var from Java in NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, nativescript, pusher

I've created a plugin which connects and subscribes to pusher channel successfully via NativeScript using this Java plugin,
now I'm trying to create an eventListener to get events in Nativescript,

this is my **Java plugin**:

```
public class PusherAndroid {

    public void connectToPusher(String app_key, String channel_name, String event_name) {

        PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setCluster("eu");
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher(app_key, options);

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                System.out.println("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                        " from " + change.getPreviousState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        Channel channel = pusher.subscribe(channel_name);

        channel.bind(event_name, new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Received event with data: " + event.toString());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and this is **my module**:

```
module.exports = {
    connect:function(app_key, channel_name, event_name) {
        var psh = new com.pxb.pusherandroid.PusherAndroid();
        psh.connectToPusher(app_key, channel_name, event_name);

        var EventListener;
        function initializeEventListener() {
            if (EventListener) {
                return;
            }
            EventListener = com.pxb.pusherandroid.PusherAndroid.extend({
                interfaces: [com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener],
                onEvent: event => {
                    console.log(event);
                }
            });
        }

        initializeEventListener();
        <HERE I NEED MY CHANNEL>.bind(event_name, new EventListener());
    }
};
```

**Now, how can I get this channel in Javascript, to use it as my defined connected channel and bind eventListener to it?**

```
Channel channel = pusher.subscribe(channel_name);
```

thank you

Comment: Even in Java, you can't access a local variable within a method from outside the method. You may have to rethink of your class structure. I'm wondering why don't you just do everything in JavaScript so you will have access to everything at one place. Or you could call onEvent from Java with desired parameters.

Comment: @Manoj can you please explain more with an example? there's not too many references for this and I have come this long with lots of trouble already, how can I improve the structure so I can control this mostly with javascript? because I'm not a Java developer "at all", thank you

Comment: Thank you @Manoj, I didn't know that I can use it directly from Javascript, I re-wrote all in Javascript and deleted my java.aar file and all works PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know how NativeScript works, but couldn't you just searialize your `Channel` to a json string, store it in a global variable on your `PusherAndroid` class and then access and desearialize it on your module?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [@Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060423/manoj), there's no need to code in Java and try to use them in Javascript,
we can directly use Java classes and methods with Javascript,
there's really not enough reference for this.

here is my module after deleting all java code and just calling the classes and methods from pusher-java-library directly:

```
module.exports = {
    connect:function(app_key, channel_name, event_name) {

        PusherOptions = com.pusher.client.PusherOptions;
        Pusher = com.pusher.client.Pusher;
        Channel = com.pusher.client.channel.Channel;
        SubscriptionEventListener = com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener;
        PusherEvent = com.pusher.client.channel.PusherEvent;

        var options = new PusherOptions().setCluster("eu");
        var pusher = new Pusher(app_key, options);

        pusher.connect();

        var channel = new Channel(pusher.subscribe(channel_name));

    }
};
```

now going to add my eventlistener with Javascript <3